# CMake find_package error on SFML with Visual Studio and vcpkg

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, sfml, vcpkg

As per the title, `CMake` is unable to find `SFML` which I installed using Microsoft's `vcpkg` tool through `CMake`s `find_package()` macro.

I have verified that `SFML` has been installed in the `vcpkg` installed directory (`~\vcpkg\installed\x86-windows`).

In addition, I have also included the toolchain file from `vcpkg` in the `CMakeSettings.json` file.

The specific error is:

```
CMake Error at ~\CMakeLists.txt:40 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" (requested
    version 2.4.2) with any of the following names:

 SFMLConfig.cmake
 sfml-config.cmake
```

`CMakeSettings.json` (simplified - only debug configuration):

```
"name": "x86-Debug",
"generator": "Visual Studio 15 2017",
"configurationType": "Debug",
"buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\build\\${name}",
"cmakeCommandArgs": "",
"buildCommandArgs": "-m -v:minimal",
"variables": [
    {
        "name": "CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE",
        "value": "C:\\Microsoft\\vcpkg\\scripts\\buildsystems\\vcpkg.cmake"
    }
]
```

`CMakeLists.txt` (also simplified):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Tempus)
add_subdirectory(src)

# Fails at this step
find_package(SFML 2.4.2 REQUIRED system window graphics)

include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_executable(Tempus ${SRC})
target_link_libraries(Tempus ${SFML_LIBRARIES})
```

I don't think I missed anything. `SFML` provides a `findSFML.cmake` which `vcpkg` should handle itself through the toolchain file (assuming I have understood their documentation correctly). I must be missing something?

Comment: `'SFML' provides a 'findSFML.cmake'` - No, SFML installation may provide `SFMLConfig.cmake`, but `Find*.cmake` scripts are provided either by CMake itself, or with **your project** (by having existed script in the your source tree). This doesn't answer your question, but just a hint.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your hint! It seems `vcpkg` provides the files and other including and linking stuff, but does not provide the `findSFML.cmake` file. Once it can find `SFML`, it sets all `CMake SFML` macros and constants. By adding the `findSFML.cmake` file manually to a CMake modules directory it has resolved my problem. Would you like to add your comment as a answer?

Comment: [Your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45479833/3440745) resolves the problem. Why have you deleted it? If you bother about plagiarism, then: 1. *Comment* is not an answer. 2. Simple "thanks" in the answer, as you have, is sufficient in the most cases. 3. Your answer contains more than the comment.

Comment: Ok, cool. I was worried about plagiarism. I've undeleted it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems `vcpkg` provides the files and other including and linking stuff, but does not provide the `findSFML.cmake` file. Once it can find `SFML`, it sets all `CMake SFML` macros and constants. By adding the `findSFML.cmake` file manually to a `CMake` modules directory it has resolved my problem.

Thanks to @Tsyvarev for the hint which led me to a solution.

I'll follow up with the `vcpkg` team to find out if this is how it should work and perhaps ask them to add this into their documentation as well.